# Why does HttpHeader X-Original-URL not exist on some pages?

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

My site using URL Rewrite to make SEO friendly URLs. This makes self-posting a form back to the same page a little tricky.

However in ColdFusion I do this for the form's action attribute:

```
<form name="formSortBy" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#StructFind(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'X-Original-URL')#">

</form>
```

The important part here is the `#StructFind(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'X-Original-URL')#` which gets me the URL of the page.

However the `X-Original-URL` key just doesn't exist on some pages so I get an error from ColdFusion saying:

```
Cannot find X-Original-URL key in structure.
The specified key, X-Original-URL, does not exist in the structure.
```

This is happening when I click to go to the homepage of a section I am in. 
So `X-Original-URL` exists if I go to `http://www.sitename.com/products/gaming` but it won't exist if I go just to `http://www.sitename.com/products`

Is there anyway to get around this or make it work like I need it to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like there is an issue between your rewrite rules and CF.

But, there is an easy fix - you can get a form to post to itself by simply not specifying the `action` attribute.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. Would it better to use a `<cfform>` tag without any attributes instead of a regular HTML `<form>` tag?

Comment: No. Never use `cfform`. Ever.You gain nothing from its use, and it will get in your way eventually.