# Redirect users to a rewritten URL after login

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a site which lets users login on any page using a simple login box at the top of the screen.

This login box has a form with a username and password field. It sends the login details to a CFC which does the backend validation stuff and then redirects the user to the page they were on.

Normally, you would use something like `<cfset SESSION.OriginalURL = CGI.ScriptName/>` to set the original URL and then use that variable in the CFC. But my site uses URL rewriting to make nice clean URLs. I want the user to be taken back to the clean URL e.g. `mysite.com/shopping/computers`

What I need to do is get the display URL that is in the address bar of the browser rather than the true ugly URL. To do this, I can use `<cfset SESSION.OriginalURL = StructFind(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'X-Original-URL')/>`

The problem is that the above method does not work on certain pages (basically pages that don't have query string variables). See my question here [Why does HttpHeader X-Original-URL not exist on some pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950039/why-does-httpheader-x-original-url-not-exist-on-some-pages)

What would be the best way to store the clean/rewritten URL and pass it to the CFC as part of the login procedure?

Comment: Can't you just check the value of of `X-Original-URL` and use it if it has a value, else use `CGI.ScriptName`?

Comment: @DigitalChris Yes I was just thinking that. The best thing to do is first check for the existence of X-Original-URL, and if it doesn't, then use CGI.ScriptName instead.

Comment: Assuming it's blank when you can't use it you can test with `<cfif len(trim(StructFind(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'X-Original-URL')))`

Comment: Yes perfect. Post it as an answer and I'll vote it as the answer. I think its better to use StructKeyExists rather than len()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for the length of the value of `X-Original-URL` and use it if it has a value, else use `CGI.ScriptName` like:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'X-Original-URL')>
   <cfset SESSION.OriginalURL = StructFind(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'X-Original-URL')/>
<cfelse>
    <cfset SESSION.OriginalURL = CGI.ScriptName/>
</cfif>
```